# Use non-breaking spaces in timestamps to prevent awkward wrapping

Tags: feature-request, design, comments

The timestamp in the comments list (at least) can wrap awkwardly making it difficult to read:

[image: Example of the awkward wrapping I described]

Since the whole timestamp is always relatively short (i.e. three words), and once it wraps it already uses a whole extra line, it would be greatly improved by preventing that block from wrapping.

Doing so is as simple as either using non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) between the words or add `white-space: nowrap;` as a CSS rule on the `.comment-date` element (exactly as defined already on the user's name):

[image: The same example with my proposed CSS fix applied]